# Category in x-axis of second chart is not coming properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using high charts for the first time in my javaScript code , I am facing an issue I have created two elements in optiondata for passing to high chart they both have all the data proper i.e number of series , data and category.
But when I render the chart the x-axis doesn't show all categories value in the second chart

Categories of x-axis for chart 1

[image]

Categories of x-axis for chart 2

[image]

Chart after rendering :

[image]

In second chart categories are not rendering from 0th position of category arrays.
Not sure why . Due to companies policy I won't be able to add my code.
But any help for direction where to look for the bug will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The number of shown categories is adapted to the amount of data. You can use the `min` and `max` properties to control the length of the axis:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [2, 2]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
        max: 4
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oe0L37v5/

**API Refernce:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/xAxis.max